# integrating @rnmapbox/maps in a nextjs13 app, doesn't render the camera on it's center location

Tags: react-native, next.js, mapbox, rnmapbox-maps

I'm trying to get `@rnmapbox/maps` working in a next13 app, I thought to start with the most basic example of them all, just a map with a Camera before moving on to displaying custom markers and data.

My Component is pretty straight forward and looks like this:

```
import FontAwesome5 from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome5'
import * as Mapbox from '@rnmapbox/maps'
import * as Location from 'expo-location'
import { Box, Icon } from 'native-base'
import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react'

export const Map = () => {
  const [location, setLocation] = useState<
    undefined | Location.LocationObjectCoords
  >(undefined)
  const mapRef= useRef<Mapbox.MapView>(null)

  useEffect(() => {
    const setCurrentLocation = async () => {
      const { status } = await Location.requestForegroundPermissionsAsync()
      if (status !== 'granted') {
        console.error('Permission to access location not granted')
        return
      }

      const currentLocation = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync()
      setLocation(currentLocation.coords)
    }
    setCurrentLocation()
  }, [])

  return (
    <Mapbox.MapView style={{ flex: 1 }} ref={mapRef}>
      <Mapbox.Camera
        zoomLevel={14}
        centerCoordinate={[-73.970895, 40.723279]}
      />
    </Mapbox.MapView>
  )
}
```

The reason we're using `@rnmapbox/maps` is because we need to have a map component for both our mobile app as our web-app and 1 codebase is less to maintain than 2 :D

Our Web-App is running on NextJS13 and we're importing the component that contains the Map Component in a dynamic way without SSR. But on Pageload the map gets rendered but it doesn't take the centerCoordinates or the zoomLevel of the Camera component into account. I've noticed that when I start the application without the Camera component in it and then add it while the dev server is running, the hot-reload triggers something that does render the map with the correct centerCoordinates (not the correct zoomLevel though).

Any help or examples are highly appreciated!